# Contributing to Monerobase

Tags: monero-community

Who created the [Monerobase wiki](https://www.monerobase.com/Main_Page)? Can anyone contribute to it? What measures are in place to prevent or remedy malicious editing from unknown parties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Donkey provided a good answer for who [created Monerobase](https://www.reddit.com/user/aerbax/) and who is allowed to [contribute](https://monerobase.com/Special:CreateAccount). I will try to answer your third question about malicious editing.

From [Monerobase](https://monerobase.com/Main_Page):

> Please keep in mind that a wiki is collaborative. Your page may be edited by someone else to adjust grammar, expansion of the data, renaming the page, adding a template, etc. This is a good thing! It allows you to start an idea and have it expanded by others until it becomes something of great benefit to the community.

The above does not prevent malicious editing, but it will allow others to make corrections and revert malicious edits when they are discovered. Anyone who registers an account is free to not only contribute, but edit the contributions of others.

Anonymous users can also contribute, but there work will not show up immediately until it is approved. This is a safeguard which helps make it more difficult to add malicious entries to the site.

If abuse were ever to become a problem administrators have [additional options](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Contents) including blocking of users, IP addresses and protecting pages.

Answer (score 4):

Monerobase is run and maintained by community member [Aerbax](https://hellomonero.com/page/contact).

Anyone is free to [create an account](https://monerobase.com/Special:CreateAccount) and contribute to the wiki.